# The English equivalent of the Arabic: “Something is innocent of you”

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

It is used when someone claims to be something, and the other person nullifies his claim. It's like saying they are a liar and that particular thing doesn't have anything to do with him or her.

For example:

> A: I am the custodian of democracy.
>   B: Democracy is *innocent of you*.
>   (Democracy has nothing to do with you, you're lying.)

and

> A: I am a patriot.
>   B: Patriotism *is innocent of you*.

Is there an English equivalent that expresses this idea?

Comment: You could say, "I doubt that the two of you [that is, the person being addressed and democracy, say, or patriotism] are at all well acquainted."

Comment: B: You are the *antithesis* of _____.  ?

Comment: You said it well yourself:  . . . . . .. . . . . . . "[X] has nothing to do with you."

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, "[X] has nothing to do with you" may not be the best choice, because it also has a meaning which is quite literal, namely "[X] is none of your business."

Comment: Maybe something like "Uh huh, sure you are."?

Answer (score 5):

**You wouldn’t know democracy ... *if it stared you in the face!***

> [**stare in the face**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stare) *idiom* (The Free Dictionary)

When someone says this of another, they are employing hyperbole and sarcasm, since something that is *staring you in the face* ... is right before your eyes and plainly evident, so this idiom means, in effect, you not only are NOT a custodian of democracy, you don’t even know what a democracy is!  So the Arabic phrase "*innocent of you*" is a bit more ... *understated*.

Comment: Or if 'it (came up and) bit you in the ass'. +1.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: Or "You wouldn't know X from your own nose!"

Answer (score 1):

The word "innocent" has this same meaning in English, i.e., free from or devoid of.  The *OED* gives the example sentence "The sermon ... was innocent of meaning."

The use has a somewhat mocking sense.  In your examples of "innocent of you," as though involving you would be a guilty act.

Answer (score 1):

> A: I am the custodian of democracy.
>   B: Democracy? You don't **even [know the meaning of the word](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/know+the+meaning+of+the+word)**.

B is saying that A doesn't know what ‘democracy’ is; he might be implying that A is a hypocrite, a perfect idiot, or totally ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

There is a southern expression: "you and the truth are strangers"

Comment: Welcome to ELU. While this is a relevant answer, a sentence or two by way of explanation would help here, I think -- see the other answers. Stack Exchange aims at a repository of reliable and justifiable knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

A strangely unoffensive and idiomatic way to say this is **nothing could be further from the truth**. For some reason, this focuses attention on the statement and basically begs the question of lying or mistake-making.

> —used to say that something is absolutely not true. I know you think I don't care, but nothing could be further from the truth.

"Nothing Could Be Further from the Truth." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 5 May 2017.